# Where do I call the model in the ViewModel?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm learning MVVM.

I have my View filling two comboboxes from ObservableCollection properties in my ViewModel (eg. properties "**Oc1**" & "**Oc2**"). I also have a property bound to the selected item of **Oc1** (eg. property "**SelVal**") that **Oc2** depends on, so when property **SelVal** is changed, **Oc2** needs to re-get it's data from the database.

Now, I've come up with a solution and it works for my situation but doesn't seem to adhere to the principle of a *get* accessor so I'd like to know what problem might I face down the track and what is a better solution?

My current solution is:

The *get* accessor of **Oc2** queries the database and sets it's private field to the value returned from the database (which the View uses). So when **SetVal** is changed, I simply call this.RaisePropertyChanged("**Oc2**") in the **SetVal** *set* accessor and the View asks for **Oc2**, which in turn queries the database and returns the updated list.
The problem is that I'm not using the *get* accessor for what it is meant for, as I'm assigning it's value in it. But what I like about it is it's self-contained (ie. I don't need a "BindOc2" method which I'd have to call in the constructor and then again in the SelVal *set* accessor). Please advise. And what's a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your suspicion is correct, this way breaks the MVVM model and fails to use mechanisms that can simplify your work, like the triggers in [System.Windows.Interactivity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interactivity%28v=expression.40%29.aspx) which is available in the [Expression Blend SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=10801).

Loading the data in the getter is begging for trouble. It binds your model to the data access code, makes testing harder and the code more complex by mixing different concerns in the same property. Besides, Murphy's law dictates that at some point you will just want to set the property without reloading from the database.

A better solution is to extract the data loading code in a separate method that can be called by a command or a trigger. This method will either modify the Oc2 collection's contents or simply replace it with a new collection. In any case, the property setter will raise the proper notification and the second combo will be updated.

The following example comes from [fabien's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950501/how-do-you-handle-a-combobox-selectionchanged-in-mvvm/5825183#5825183) in a similar SO question:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="fileComboBox" ItemsSource="{Binding FileList, Mode=TwoWay}">                  
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction 
                        Command="{Binding SelectionChangedCommand}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItems,           
                        ElementName=fileComboBox}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>

    </ComboBox>
```

Most frameworks provide support for this design. [Caliburn.Micro](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/) provides  [actions](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=All%20About%20Actions&referringTitle=Documentation) that will call a ViewModel method when a UI event occurs, and a shortcut syntax to avoid writing the trigger XAML and the corresponding command. It simply connects the event to a ViewModel method. The XAML can be as simple as this:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="Oc1" 
    cal:Message.Attach="[Event SelectionChanged] = 
                        [Action ReloadFor($this.SelectedItem)]" />
```

The `$this` value is another shorthand that references the ComboBox itself.

If you don't want to use triggers, you can bind the SelectedItem property of your combo to a ViewModel property and execute the Reload method whenever this property changes, eg.:

```
<ComboBox ... SelectedItem={Binding CurrentOC2,Mode=TwoWay} />
```

Comment: Your solution sounds wise (especially with Murphy's Law). Do you suggest I have a separate method for all my comboboxes? Because in a previous non-MVVM project I had over 10 methods (BindSites, BindNames, BindBusiness, etc) and I ended up grouping them into other methods for initialization etc - they seemed to be unnecessarily separate from the properties. But then again, I've never successfully designed a big project so that could be the right way...

Answer (score 2):

I understand your reticence since yes, raising PropertyChanged for a different property feels  a bit hacky, but it's not too bad IMHO.

A more natural way would be to do your database pull in the `SelVal` setter, since this is what is triggering the change of data. You then set `Oc2` to the results which will automatically raise a `PropertyChanged` as it should.

The only problem with this is that you might be pulling db results unnecessarily if your Oc2 getter is never accessed, but given that you know your view will always want them I'd be tempted to change to this solution.

Comment: Thanks for your input Gaz. The problem you highlighted is the main reason I'm reluctant to put the db pull in the SelVal setter. Maybe it's just me, but another reason I have is that it's not immediately traceable from Oc2 should down the track I forget I put it in there.

Answer (score 1):

The way you do it is fine. Properties set and get methods are usualy good for this kind of Binding

Answer (score 1):

So to rephrase you have something similar to Category, CurrentCategory, and SubCategory.  When CurrentCategory changes, SubCategory needs to refresh.

I think your way is fine. Especially in MVVM I see this type of thing all over the place.  Outside of MVVM it's fairly common to have property getters hitting the database for lazy load scenarios (usually invoking some sort of a service method, not inlining everything).

Comment: Thanks Kenneth. When you say all over the place, is that in large projects? Because as Panagiotis said, one day I may want to set the property and I won't be able to.

Comment: Yes in large projects.  However in large projects, view models usually only represent logic intended for the view (non ui business related logic is usually implemented in some sort of a domain/business/service layer).  They usually match the functionality of the ui fairly precisely.  If the ui doesn't allow you to set a collection of subcategories, then usually I don't have a public setter to match in my view model.

Answer (score 1):

If those data are not changing, you could have that in your viewmodel.

Always querying the database should not be the first option.

you could do this in a quite simple way:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> cache;
...
List<string> subCat;
if cache.TryGetValue (selVal, out subCat) 
{
    // no need to call database
}
else
{
   // else call database
   // insert result in cache
}
```

Comment: I'll try incorporate your idea Mare, ta.